# C# Delete row from multiple tables

Tags: c#, database, linq, mdf

Situation: I have 3 tables:

- `movies` (`pk:movietitle, movielength`....etc)
- `rentals` (`pk:personid, fk:movietitle,`...etc)
- `rentingpeople` (`pk+fk:personid, name, phone`...etc)

On my form there is a listbox bindingsourced with the movie titles, next to the listbox there are textboxes bindingsourced from `db.movies`

When someone click on the `rentthismovie` button I would like to delete the current rental data about that movie from table `rentals` and `rentingpeople`.

I wrote the first part and get an error because of foreign keys problem (I mentioned primary key as `pk` and foreign key as `fk` in the tables above)

```
var search = (from g in db.Rentals 
              where g.Movietitle == (string)listBox1.SelectedValue select g).First();

db.Rentals.DeleteObject(search);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_Rentingpeople_Rentals\". The conflict occurred in database \"C:\USERS\PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\FILMEK\FILMEK\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE1.MDF\", table \"dbo.Rentingpeople\", column 'personid'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Because of the primary-foreign key connection I must delete the data from `rentingpeople` table too as I read from this error but I can't really find a working solution.

Comment: Do you have any other table where you keep information of people that are "members" and can rent, other than your `rentingpeople` table?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the db design

```
movies(pk:movietitle,movielength....etc)
rentals(pk:personid,fk:movietitle,...etc)
rentingpeople(pk+fk:personid,name,phone...etc)
```

If I got this right, `movies` contains the list of movies, `rentingpeople` is the list of people who are renting or have rented, and `rentals` tracks rentals.  If so, *rentingpeople.personid* should be a pk, and *rentals.personid* should be an fk to the other, like this:

- movies(pk:movietitle,movielength....etc)
- **rentals(fk:personid,fk:movietitle,...etc)**
- **rentingpeople(pk:personid,name,phone...etc)**

if you want to improve search on rentals (assuming any one person can exercise multiple rentals at the same time) you can introduce a non-unique index on personid, or a composite unique index to personid and movietitle on table `rentals`

Comment: i changed now i get the error: Unable to update the EntitySet 'Rentals' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: @user3551399 Are you using EF? I think it's a problem with ef that you need a pk in every table, if that's the case, put a PK in rentals table, for example you can make `PK(personid, movietitle)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all the PK and not null references to the object you are deleting before you delete object itself.
You can change non nullable columns to nullable ones if logic allows.

```
var rentalsToBeDeleted = db.Rentals.Where(o =>o.movieid == movieid).ToList();
for (int i = rentalsToBeDeleted.count; i < 0; i--)
{
 db.Rentals.DeleteObject(rentalsToBeDeleted.elementAt(i));
}
```

after all the referenced deleted.

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

writing without VS so mistakes are likely but you should get the idea.

Comment: everything allows nulls but primary and foreign keys. I can't find the way to delete the personid from rentingpeople which is connected to the rentals personid who rented the selected movie

Comment: unfortunately elementsat and delete : does not contain definition and no extension method...

Comment: add to list at the end of db.Rentals.Where(o =>o.movieid == movieid).ToList();

Comment: still.. :( anyway i changed to o.movieid==listbox1.selectedvalu or it is underlined too with red and i need to search for the selectedmovie

Comment: hm the code clean now,but nothing deleted :( now i have 3 same movie titles in the rentals table,none of them gets deleted

Comment: check in debugger if there are elements in the list var rentalsToBeDeleted = db.Rentals.Where(o =>o.movieid == movieid).ToList();